# First Word or Letter taking two lines or three in a paragraph

Tags: formatting

Some articles start with its first word or letter in its first paragraph taking up the space of two lines or three lines. For example, it might look like the picture below (ignoring the rules). Is there a way to do this in LaTeX, please? Thank you! I did not find any similar question. Please let me know if this is a duplicate.

[image]

Comment: Search this site for `lettrine`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Updated Answer

The method demonstrated below is now available as a package, [cfr-initials](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cfr-initials) from CTAN and is included in TeX Live. The package provides 23 `.sty` files. Each one provides LaTeX commands supporting one of the 23 fonts provided by [initials](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/initials).

[Two of these fonts appear to be identical or almost identical. This is not my fault!]

You can then use the initials with [lettrine](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) by loading the relevant package and using the commands explained in the documentation for `cfr-initials` and `lettrine`.

The following example demonstrates all 23 fonts. Obviously, you should not try combining them all in a real document!

[image: 23 lettrines with <code>initials</code> and <code>cfr-initials</code>]

### Code for demo

```
\documentclass[british,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[headheight=12pt,vscale=.95]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{Acorn, AnnSton, ArtNouv, ArtNouvc, Carrickc, Eichenla, Eileen, EileenBl, Elzevier, GotIn, GoudyIn, Kinigcap, Konanur, Kramer, MorrisIn, Nouveaud, Romantik, Rothdn, Royal, Sanremo, Starburst, Typocaps, Zallman}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\lettrinetest[1]{% text is from the kantlipsum package
  \setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}%
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{fnc}%
  \gdef\fontlist{#1}%
  \@for \xx:=\fontlist \do {%
        %       \lettrinetest{\xx}
        \renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\xx}%
        \lettrine{A}{s} any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
        used as a canon for our understanding.}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\lettrinetest{%
  \Royal,
  \Romantik,
  \ArtNouvfamily,
  \EileenBlfamily,
  \Zallmanfamily,
  \Sanremofamily,
  \Konanurfamily,
  \Starburstfamily,
  \Typocapsfamily,
  \ArtNouvcfamily,
  \Kinigcapfamily,
  \Kramerfamily
}
\clearpage
\lettrinetest{%
  \Acornfamily,
  \AnnStonfamily,
  \Elzevier,
  \Rothdnfamily,
  \Eichenlafamily,
  \MorrisInfamily,
  \Carrickcfamily,
  \Nouveaudfamily,
  \GoudyInfamily,
  \Eileenfamily,
  \GotInfamily
}
\end{document}
```

## Original Answer

Standard TeX distributions come with a set of ornamental and decorative fonts suitable for lettrines. These do not have `.sty` files unless you write them and the `.fd` files are not named according to the standard schema.

However, if you provide your own `.sty` file or equivalent code, they are easy to use for this purpose.

Here are just two of the twenty-three possibilities included in `initials`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\input Typocaps.fd

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Typocapsfamily}{%
  \fontencoding{U}%
  \fontseries{xl}%
  \fontshape{n}%
  \fontfamily{Typocaps}%
  \selectfont}

\input Kramer.fd

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Kramerfamily}{%
  \fontencoding{U}%
  \fontseries{xl}%
  \fontshape{n}%
  \fontfamily{Kramer}%
  \selectfont}

\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}

\begin{document}
  \renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\Kramerfamily}
  \lettrine{A}{s} any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
  used as a canon for our understanding.
  The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena.
  Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.
  Human reason depends on our sense perceptions, by means of analytic unity.
  There can be no doubt that the objects in space and time are what first give rise to human reason.

  \renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\Typocapsfamily}
  \lettrine{A}{s} any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
  used as a canon for our understanding.
  The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena.
  Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.
  Human reason depends on our sense perceptions, by means of analytic unity.
  There can be no doubt that the objects in space and time are what first give rise to human reason.
\end{document}
```

[image: lettrines]

Comment: I never thought about doing this… this is gorgeous!

Comment: @SeanAllred It was the black background in the image the OP posted that reminded me of these. I set up `.sty` files for these fonts because they were there and looked interesting, but then never quite figured out what to do with them!

Comment: @HarishKumar All 23 of them? They aren't very long, but I don't know how useful that would be!

Comment: @HarishKumar  [Coming soon](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cfr-initials). Will that do?

Comment: @HarishKumar You realise you have to test it now and let me know what the bugs are? ;)

Comment: @cfr My pleasure. Where are the files? :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar See answer above. But I don't think it will be on all mirrors yet. Should be in a day or so, though. When I asked them if the files were too trivial to be worth server space, they indicated that for a package of less than 1MB, if even one person used it, they would like to have it. So there you go!

Comment: @HarishKumar Now in TeX Live ;).

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks! What's the error?

Comment: @cfr `undefined control sequence` on lines 148, 152 and 154. log here: http://pastebin.com/wLRBcmKf lines 1019 onwards.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks! 2 errors actually. I just uploaded a very minor update to CTAN. I should have noticed the problem. Serves me right for using arara which is hiding the error, for some reason.

Comment: @cfr: No errors now. I didn't install it yet, waiting for miktex portal. :-) Thanks.