# Back to normal font after decorative initial

Tags: fonts, lettrine

I would like to start each chapter of my thesis with a decorative initial.
Specifically, I'd like to use the Typographer Caps (see [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/allfonts.html)).

In the sty file I set my default font environment:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
```

and added the command to have the specific decorative initials font:

```
\input Typocaps.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Typocaps}{xl}{n}}
```

Then, in the tex file corresponding to one of the chapters, I typed:

```
\chapter{First chapter}

\initfamily{T}
he quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

but as a result the whole chapter gets printed with that decorative font.

What am I doing wrong?

#### An alternative way

Taking inspiration from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/769/how-can-i-create-documents-in-latex-using-a-calligraphic-first-letter-for-chapte) great question, I could obtain a fairly good result by adding

```
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

in the sty file, and

```
\lettrine[lines=3]{\textcolor{BrickRed}T}{he quick brown fox}
```

in the tex file.

Nevertheless, there is no font switch between the initial capital letter and the following text, which is the reason why I'm asking this question.

Comment: your `\initfamily` does not take an argument so the syntax is  `{\initfamily T}` not `\initfamily{T}`

Comment: If you use the `lettrine` solution, then you simply need to do: `\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{}` (the default is `\scshape`).

Comment: You can see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236405/first-word-or-letter-taking-two-lines-or-three-in-a-paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it with `lettrine`:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{Typocaps}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{BrickRed}\Typocapsfamily{}}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[findent=3pt, nindent =0pt]{I}{n} former days -- that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to find out all about them.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neat and very informative answer, thank you!